# Указать дату при вызове хранимой процедуры Oracle

Tags: java, oracle

Есть хранимая процедура, которую пытаюсь вызвать в приложении на Java. Процедура принимает на вход две даты, а на выходе курсор. в БД в таблицах все даты хранятся в виде 06.12.2018. Как мне правильно указать даты при вызове процедуры? Нужно указать даты 01.11.2018 по 30.11.2018

```
try (Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection()) {
    CallableStatement cstmt = connection.prepareCall("{call pkg_report.report_usl(?, ?, ?)}");
    cstmt.setDate(1, ДАТА С);
    cstmt.setDate(2, ДАТА ПО);
    cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
    cstmt.execute();
    ResultSet resultSet = (ResultSet) cstmt.getObject(3);
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        System.out.println(resultSet.getString("fam"));
    }

}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: А Вы пробовали это запускать? `cstmt.setDate()` ожидает на вход объект типа `java.util.Date`, и ему всё равно в каком он формате.

Comment: Я писал так SimpleDateFormat formatDate2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.M.YYYY");
        Date parsedDate2 = formatDate2.parse("31.12.2018");  выдает ошибку Cannot resolve method 'setDate(int, java.util.Date)'

Comment: По-моему там нужно именно java.sql.Date

Comment: Да, точно, `java.sql.Date`, извиняюсь, давно не заглядывал в jdbc. Вы можете обернуть получившийся у Вас Date в `java.sql.Timestamp`. Должно получиться так `csmt.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(date.getTime()))`

Comment: Спасибо, но все равно не понятно как указать дату, которая мне нужна. Хочу указать дату 01.11.2018 делаю так SimpleDateFormat formatDate1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.M.YYYY");
        Date parsedDate1 = formatDate1.parse("01.11.2018"); но в итоге дата оказывается что 01.01.2018

Comment: Для 01.11.2018 паттерн будет `dd.M.yyyy`